# Issue with LVM not able to add new drives

Tags: server, partitioning, lvm

```
Fdisk, lv/pv/vgdisplay:

anubis@Anubis:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for anubis:

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
45 heads, 63 sectors/track, 344540 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1b231dca 

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   976773167   488385560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
45 heads, 63 sectors/track, 344540 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x85e38cb4

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   976773167   488385560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6b680487

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  1953525167   976761560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00009d51

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *        2048   195311615    97654784   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2       195311616  3907029167  1855858776   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vgpool-storage: 2900.5 GB, 2900499628032 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 352632 cylinders, total 5665038336 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vgpool-storage doesn't contain a valid partition table
anubis@Anubis:~$ sudo lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Name                /dev/vgpool/storage
VG Name                vgpool
LV UUID                C56qjD-X92X-HguJ-1b3n-OOUN-dDBE-fo1fN0
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Status              available
# open                 0
LV Size                2.64 TiB
Current LE             691533
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:0

anubis@Anubis:~$ sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               vgpool
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  20
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                1
Open LV               0
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               2.64 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              691556
Alloc PE / Size       691533 / 2.64 TiB
Free  PE / Size       23 / 92.00 MiB
VG UUID               XAgeo7-kfnx-ew9Z-qFEn-AQzZ-26Fv-YDLr8D

anubis@Anubis:~$ sudo pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdc1
VG Name               vgpool
PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              238466
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          238466
PV UUID               vgZcil-AgYl-nOHy-oPq7-pc7m-ybDV-qpwHs5

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdd2
VG Name               vgpool
PV Size               1.73 TiB / not usable 2.09 MiB
Allocatable           yes
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              453090
Free PE               23
Allocated PE          453067
PV UUID               P9pAmT-cPAD-bS2H-XGcN-9wpU-6c4g-QcPJyL

anubis@Anubis:~$ sudo vgextend vgpool /dev/sda1
Device /dev/sda1 not found (or ignored by filtering).
Unable to add physical volume '/dev/sda1' to volume group 'vgpool'.

sudo pvscan
[sudo] password for anubis:
PV /dev/sdc1   VG vgpool   lvm2 [931.51 GiB / 0    free]
PV /dev/sdd2   VG vgpool   lvm2 [1.73 TiB / 92.00 MiB free]
Total: 2 [2.64 TiB] / in use: 2 [2.64 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

I have a volume group setup with two physical volumes. That is working fine, no issues. I am trying to add /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1. Both have been partitioned and formatted, as you can see. The first two drives added just fine while the other two just give me an error.

I am really at the end of my realm, and i need help.

The purpose of this server is mainly as a file server. It is running

> Ubuntu server 12.04.2
>   four sata drives, 2x 500GB, 1x 1TB, and 1x 2TB.

I have a single ext partition on the 2TB for ubuntu and all its needs. The rest I want to use as a large storage place for music movies and photos.

Comment: Did you create the physical volumes sda1 and sdb1 with `pvcreate`?

Comment: What @GeraldSchneider said. Additionally: `sudo pvscan` should yield both `sda1` and `sdb1` after doing so and you should be able to add it.

Comment: We need more information. How did you create the LVM (PV) ? What command are you running and what error message did you get ?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: yes all pv's were created using pvcreate

Comment: @qertvdijk: see the original post. i dont see sda1 or sdb1

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: i included the error ive been getting, see original post "Device /dev/sda1 not found (or ignored by filtering).
Unable to add physical volume '/dev/sda1' to volume group 'vgpool'."

Comment: @qertvdijk: sorry, should have said, i added the output of pvscan to the original post

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, sda1 and sdb1 both retained previous volume group associations. I had believed that all traces of the first vg i created, as a test, had been removed. they had not. in order for me to wipe the drives i needed to do:

```
sudo pvremove /dev/sdb1 -ff
Labels on physical volume "/dev/sdb1" successfully wiped
```

after that i was able to successfully able to readd the drives via `pvcreate` and `vgextend`. the rest was a breeze.